# How to properly use .scss modules with React components

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass

I have a question regarding how to correctly use .scss modules(and common css modules) when it comes to use the same .scss module in several components at once.

For instance: if a parent & its children need to access the same exact .scss module, which way is the best to access the module?

Assume I have a .scss module which contains all styles and a component AudioPlayer that has a structure like this:

```
 import audioPlayerModule from './SCSS/AudioPlayer.module.scss';
 /*Some code*/
 return (
    <div className={audioPlayerModule.audio_container}>
        <LeftControls/>
        <CenterControls />
        <RightControls/>
    </div>)
```

The main AudioPlayer component uses the module audioPlayerModule. Then let's say I need this module again inside the child component LeftControls:

```
import audioPlayerModule from './SCSS/AudioPlayer.module.scss';
const LeftControls = () => {
      return (
      <div className={audioPlayerModule.left_controls_container}></div>
);
}
```

Thus I have imported the same .scss module "audioPlayerModule" to parent & each of its children. Is there any better way to do it without using "props.children"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass className props to your child components

```js
<LeftControl className={audioPlayerModule.left_controls_container}/>
```

and then spread this props in child

```js
const LeftControls = ({props}) => {
      return (
      <div {...props}></div>
);
```

Comment: Wouldn't passing down the className to each child produce a lot of trash code due to prop drilling?

Comment: With the approach I mentioned, prop drilling is happening only at one level. If only that's your use case I think it pretty much acceptable to prop drill.